# How to pass SIGALRM to a program which completes execution within microseconds?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have a C program which computes the first n prime numbers if n is passed as an argument.

```
$ ./prime 5
2
3
5
7
11
```

The logic of the program allows me to enter into a desired function if I can give `SIGALRM` to the process of the program.

So basically I have to enter

```
kill -14 <PID of prime>
```

in another terminal when 'prime' just starts executing, before entering the loop to find prime numbers. It is also to be noted that the PID changes every time the program is executed.

How can I concatenate all these actions and perform this in a single line command?

Comment: Perhaps `./prime 5; kill -14 $?`

Comment: @bishop It won't work as with semicolon, the commands would be executed sequentially

Comment: Try `./prime 5 & kill -14 $!`

Comment: Right, one of a couple of typos. Try again: `./prime 5 & kill -14 $!`

Comment: Impossible with the command line. You mentioned you can't run gdb on a target machine. Can you compile and run your code there?

Comment: @bishop It is giving me a couple of PIDs. Which I am not sure of what process. The program did not enter the prime number finding loop, however it didn't recieve the interrupt signal either [ or the warning it should have fired to std out is not visible]

Comment: @user58697 Yes I can, but I am supposed to use a defined binary which has a particular gid set.

Comment: Perhaps the signal was sent before the sighandlers were registered. There is a both a no-earlier-than limit and a no-later-than limit. You may be better off with a design change: command line option, read from stdin, etc.

Comment: You could also call `raise(SIGALRM);` somewhere in the program. Then you get to control precisely when the signal happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make `prime` block on a write to a full pipe.

To make this work, you need to know exactly what the capacity of a pipe on your system is. On most systems, this is 64 KB -- 65536 bytes. Some obscure UNIX systems (not Linux, and not Mac OS X) may have a different pipe capacity, so if this doesn't work you may want to check this.

```
( dd if=/dev/zero bs=65536 count=1 ; ./prime ) | ( sleep 3; cat )
sleep 1
killall -ALRM prime
```

The first command constructs a pipe which performs the following actions on the writing end:

- Write 65536 null bytes to the pipe, filling it up.
- Start `prime`.

and on the reading end:

- `sleep` for 3 seconds.
- Have `cat` read everything out of the pipe and print it until it reaches EOF.

When `prime` starts, the pipe is full of 64KB of null bytes, and the process on the other end is `sleep 3`, which isn't reading from the pipe. As soon as it starts trying to `write()` its first line of output, it blocks. While this is happening, the `sleep 1` will finish, and an alarm signal is delivered to `prime`, which is conveniently blocked. This makes it do… whatever it does when it gets SIGALRM.

Once the `sleep 3` finishes, `cat` helpfully reads everything out of the pipe and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite the unusual purpose for a signal!

The easiest way I can see to do it is to run `prime` in gdb, and use its `signal` function to send the signal to your program.

Comment: Yes you are right. Quite unusual for a normal program. But this is a purposeful piece of code for a challenge. Now to the point, the binary is on a different machine, on which I don't have much privilege or gdb. That's why I am looking for a single line shell command for the purpose.

Comment: What makes you believe that doing it in a single line will manage to send the signal fast enough?  If you're fast enough, you many not even task-switch back to the shell to process the next command before `prime` terminates.  The Linux scheduler typically operates on scales of milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: Apologies if I weren't clear. I didn't just mean that I am looking for a single line command. I am looking for a way to pass **SIGALRM** to a process, right when it starts where I just have the process name. So the challenge here for me is in identifying the _process ID_ which I have to supply with _kill -14_ . I tried _pidof_ but the problem is I again need the pid of the process at that point of time while I am passing the kill. I assume that now it may be clear that why I am looking for a way to pass it in a single command.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/293632/how-do-i-start-a-process-in-suspended-state-under-linux may be as close as you'll get.  The answers generally suspend the bash shell before starting your code, so you get the PID of your shell ahead of time and it works.  However, you're still at the mercy of the scheduler.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the easiest way to make sure `SIGALRM` gets raised at a particular time is to add:

```
raise(SIGALRM);
```

at a particular point in the program. Then `SIGALRM` will always be raised when that call executes.

Comment: Not applicable here as I am supposed to manipulate the executable, rather than modifying the code and creating an alternate one.